# Access db query

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a challenge with the following string:

```
Datedeath: IIf([Members.Status]=[“DA”] Or [“DB”] Or [“DJ”] Or [“DC”], else [members.deathdate] "29/02/1844"
```

Might someone be able to guide me as to how to write this iif statement please?

Comment: Can you describe what result you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: yes. If the members status is one of the following status indicated, da, db and so on AND the deathdate field is blank then the deathdate field will fill with 29/02/1844.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the condition fulfilled, set new date or leave it

```
[members.deathdate]:IIf ((([Members.Status] = "DA"  Or [Members.Status] = "DB" Or [Members.Status] = "DJ" Or [Members.Status] = "DC") And ([members.deathdate] = "" Or IsNull([members.deathdate]))), "29/02/1844", [members.deathdate])
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I received the following error report: The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: 1) Shouldn't the check be for `IS NULL` instead of `=""`? 2) Why do you have square brackets around the string literals -- `["DC"]` instead of `"DC"`? 3) The parentheses around the blank check is unnecessary. 4) How did you get smart quotes in your expression?

Comment: If `DeathDate` is a Date/Time then there is no need to check for an empty string, just for nullity. Also, the expression I had in mind is `AND Members.DeathDate IS NULL`, which is more efficient as it uses an SQL expression instead of the VBA-exposed IsNull function.